# Bootstrap array overlap form input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I created a small demo at http://jsfiddle.net/m0pey3ev.
Only need to click on `Tiroir` to see the result.

In a panel, I have a bootstrap table and a form input.

```
<div id="setupOptionDivTemplate">

    <table id="setupDrawerTableResult" style="min-height:200" data-show-header="true" class="table table-striped" data-toggle="table" data-height="330">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>Nom</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr data-index="0">
               <td style="" data-drawer-id="1">01-A</td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>

</div>

<form id="setupOptionForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" data-fv-framework="bootstrap" data-fv-icon-valid="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" data-fv-icon-invalid="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-fv-icon-validating="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="setupOption" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Option</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="setupOption" name="name" placeholder="Entrer le nom  de l'option">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button id="setupDrawerSave" type="button"  class="btn btn-primary">Sauvegarder</button>
                <button id="setupDrawerReset" type="reset"  class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

I have a table and a form input under it. Table overlap the form input.

[image]
  Edit

if i don't put the panel in a tab-panel and this one in a tab content, that work.

http://jsfiddle.net/33h53t4m/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jksheth/m0pey3ev/5/

```
.form-horizontal .form-group{
    margin-top:20px;
}
```